# mysql root@localhost has no privileges

Tags: mysql

I have tried to make a table on mysql but I keep getting .

```
CONSOLE: [SEVERE] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

but I should have everything allowed

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*60BF85ECA0CB9AEA703C24F4B193EDE2A32A7879' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: the root account requires a password. The error message says you tried to do it without a password.

Comment: This is a programming website, this question belongs on dba.se.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO And then DBA's will say "What's this Java you speak of?" :)

Comment: [dba.stackechange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Well, it seems that this is your problem (emphasis mine):

> `CONSOLE: [SEVERE] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` **(using password: NO)**

Apparently you didn't specify a password in the connection details.